# Time Length Of Subset

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-2010, subset

I am using Excel 2010, and have access to PowerPivot.

I am trying to find out how to work out the time each subset lasted.

Here is an example of the data:

```
Run:          Date:       Time:    

A    31/01/2018    20:00:00

A    31/01/2018    21:00:00

A    31/01/2018    22:00:00

A    31/01/2018    23:00:00

A    01/02/2018    00:00:00

A    01/02/2018    01:00:00

B    04/02/2018    10:00:00

B    04/02/2018    11:00:00
```

etc.

I want to find out the length of time between the first row and the last row in each different subset, so that the output will be:

```
Run:    Time Taken:

A    05:00:00

B    01:00:00
```

TIA,

Teuthis

Comment: are the rows always in chronological order?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Yes, they are

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to answer the question myself, for anyone who has the same issue. Here is a picture of the solved spreadsheet, with the formula in red.

[Spreadsheet inc solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgIHb.png)

The formula is:

=(LOOKUP(A15,$A$2:$A$9,($B$2:$B$9+$C$2:$C$9)))-((INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(A15,$A$2:$A$9,0)))+INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MATCH(A15,$A$2:$A$9,0)))

=(LOOKUP(*search term*,*array to search*,(*date to search in*+*time to search in*)))-((INDEX(*date to search in*,MATCH(*search term*,*array to search*,0)))+INDEX(*time to search in*,MATCH(*search term*,*array to search*,0)))

**NOTE**:
You will need to make sure that the times are all in hh:mm and not dd/mm/yy hh:mm, otherwise the ones close to midnight will be incorrect.